# Align texts in spans

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get "Try these" on the same line and after that the "apples" block as it shows now. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.aaa {
 display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
 background-color: #000;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.aaa span {
  display: inline;
 color: red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.q {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="q">
<a href="#" class="aaa">Try these <span>apples apples apples apples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples apples</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `white-space:nowrap` to the main container and put it back to initial in the apples container

*I also added a non-breakable space to create space between texts*

```css
.aaa {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aaa span {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: initial;
}

.q {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="q">
  <a href="#" class="aaa">Try these &nbsp;<span>apples apples apples apples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples apples</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes you need to make:

- Make both `q class container` and the `anchor class aaa` as `flex`, this ensures that you have your anchor aligned in the same line and then the span inside the anchor also aligned as demonstrated. Then use the property of flex:1 on both of their child containers i.e for `q => aaa` and for `aaa=>span`. This ensures that they can flexible when resized.

```css
.aaa {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.aaa span {
  flex: 1;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.q {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="q">
  <a href="#" class="aaa"> Try these &nbsp;<span> apples apples apples apples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples applesapples apples apples</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: almost, but the "apples" section has to show as in my snippet. So underneath eachother.

Comment: @raulbaros Updated.

Comment: the only issue with this (not a big issue) is that you lose the continuous line under text, they are splitted now .. am wondering why by the way

Comment: Yeah well, since span wasn't a direct child of class q container but a subchild of the anchor tag, I improvised.

Comment: the solution is fine, but was thinking why the line behave like this, it can be interesting to find the explanation :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif It was because I added a margin of 10px on the span, replaced that with a &nbsp; and it works fine.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was solving another question and yeah I just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

try putting it into a [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) where "Try these" will take 4/12 columns and apples will take 8/12. Or put two sections in a [table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp), just make sure borders are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

display: flex; takes each block of content and treats it like its own entity, then tries to set them however you have your flex settings. In this case you are using the defaults.

Basically, it's doing this

```
[any amount]  [any other]
[of content]  [content  ]
```

You want to set the flex direction so they are on top of each other, so try this:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

This should make the output:

```
[any amount of content]
[any other content]
```

Comment: you may edit your answer to include the jsfiddle instead of adding a comment ;)

Comment: Truth be told, I misread his post and had to edit my comment like three times. I felt dumb so just made a JSFiddle and threw it on there. Rereading his post again, I think it's also wrong, and I quit. haha.